# WP. Запись спаршеных данных в таблицу

Tags: php, wordpress, парсер, php-curl

Есть табличка в базе WP `wp_fg_tournaments` следующего вида:

[image: таблица]

Стоит задача добавить в неё строчку, сформированную из спаршенных данных `curl` запроса. Код выглядит так:

```
<?php

function curl_get($url, $referer = 'https://www.google.com'){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // загрузка страницы и выдача её браузеру
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($data===false) echo curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}




$html = curl_get('https://www.soccerstats.com/latest.asp?league=england');


$dom = str_get_html($html);
$title = $dom->find('h1', 0);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($title, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$newContent = $dom->saveHTML();
$html = str_get_html($newContent);  /// в $html храниться объект <h1>Premier League</h1>


/// Тут добавление в базу
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix() . 'fg_tournaments';


    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", time());
    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'id' => NULL,
            'title' => serialize($html), //// Не отрабатывает
            'description' => 'test desсription',
            'object_last_modified' => $date,
            'odject_published_up' => $date,
        ),
        array(
            '%d', // %d - значит число
            '%s', // %s - значит строка
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s'
        )

    );
    echo "DONE";
```

Для теста хочу записать `h1`, взятое из указанного адреса, и записать новую строку в базу. Но почему-то не записывает. Если просто передать вместо `'title' => serialize($html)`
`'title' => 'test title'`, то все записывает, а так не отрабатывает.
Не могу понять в чём ошибка. Думал, что curl запрос не успевает отработать до момента записи, но пишут, что нет. Подскажите, в чём может быть ошибка.

Вот что выводит `var_dump(serialize($html))`

[image: var dump]

Comment: Ну а вывести результат `serialize($html)` куда-то в лог или на экран, то что видно?

Comment: дополнил вопрос выводом

Comment: И как теперь строку в 3 тысячи символов поместить в поле varchar(128)?

Comment: Хмм, да. Чет не подумал. А есть ли способ почистить от всего лишнего ? Тут только через регулярки, или я как-то не правильно произвожу разпаршивание, и есть более правильные способы избавляться от лишнего если мне нужен по сути только `<h1>text</h1>`

Comment: Ну так надо подумать получше. Проверить что возвращает `$dom->saveHTML();`, а затем подумать - зачем я применяю функцию `str_get_html`.